# How to connect via API to an external gsuite

Tags: api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I want to get the content of some employees emails in another organization.

But I couldn't find a way to do it, when I'm outside of the organization.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried what does your research tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it based on this post:
https://medium.com/@Skaaptjop/access-gsuite-apis-on-your-domain-using-a-service-account-e2a8dbda287c

1. The organization creates a Service Account with domain-wide delegation.
2. Then in the G suite admin view, they can give only the relevant scope of permissions, in my case, I just wanted the metadata, so - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`
3. They pass me the credentials.json file of the service account they created
4. In my script, I impersonate each user, and reads the metadata of the emails (can use Message List and Message Get APIs) - it's similar to the script written in the blog post (I already have the list of the relevant emails, so I use it).

I'm still not sure it's the best way, I've reached someone on g suite team and waiting to hear back (I know Microsoft developed an API for the metadata for their services).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the Service Account is created by the organization you are trying to access data from. This is not accessing other organizations' data from your account, but using their account to access their data. Glad this works for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

The usual way of giving some users access to other users' messages is by calling [Users.settings.delegates.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/create). And in this case, as indicated in the referenced documentation, **"the delegate user must be a member of the same G Suite organization as the delegator user"**.

Also, please bear in mind that this method works via a Service Account that has been granted **domain-wide delegation**, which in any case can have access to users outside the G Suite organization.

#### Reference:

- [Gmail API: Managing Delegates](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings)
- [Gmail API: Users.settings.delegates.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/create)
- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

I hope this is of any help.